# passing callback or promise to the different module , which one is better and efficient?

Tags: callback, promise, loopbackjs

In my application, I am passing callback to different module and so on. 
Same thing I am able to achieve using bluebird promise.

According to best code practice, which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "best practice". However, you will find promises much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My concern is all about sending it to different module. Is it ok to send the promise to different module ?  In loopback js they used callback.

Comment: If that module already exists, you should check their API, and use what the module needs. If you mean the API of your module that your caller interfaces with, then returning promises is widely accepted and totally fine.